# Where is edit button in developer story section?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, user-experience, traditional-view

I wanted to update some info about me in *Developer story* section and found a quiet interesting thing. If I use a *Story view*, I can edit my job details:

> [image: story view]

but in *Traditional view* I have not found any similar button to do the same:

> [image: img2]

Am I missing something or it's a feature or a bug?